# Check if pair is empty or uninitialized

Tags: c++, std-pair

```
 int main() {

   pair<int, int> res;
   // check here pair is empty ?
   // res = make_pair(1 , 2);


   return 0;
}
```

In the above snippet what is the ideal way to check if a pair has been initilaized or not?

EDIT: As pointed out in some answers below, using the word "uninitialized" is wrong here, to be more specific how do I check if the value has been explicitly set (other than the default constructor)

Comment: Looks like a [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem

Comment: You look at your program. Is there initialisation somewhere? Then it is initialised. No initialisation? Not initialised. In your case, there is initialisation in the std::pair constructor. Since there is no such thing as empty pair, the check here is trivial.

Comment: @CinCout I wonder, in order for this not to be an XY Problem the mvce should be about a general `pair<T, U>` instead of the specific `pair<int, int>`, right?

Comment: The OP might have dumbed it down. One can only guess!

Answer (score 8):

There's no such thing as unitialized `std::pair`.

[Default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) for `std::pair` will *value-initialize* both it's members, which for pair of ints means both `int` will have value 0.

Answer (score 8):

> In the above snippet what is the ideal way to check if a pair has been initilaized or not?

You check your favorite language reference and realize that

- `std::pair` requires default-constructible types and
- the `std::pair` default constructor default-initializes its data members.

And hence,

```
std::pair<int, int> res;
```

will result in `res.first` and `res.second` both be zero.

---

When you need to add an additional empty state to an object, it's always an option to explicitly wrap it into a `std::optional` (or `boost::optional` if you can't use C++17). This way, you can always check whether you have a meaningful `std::pair` or not:

```
#include <optional>

std::optional<std::pair<int, int>> res;

if (res) // the pair is initialized and usable
   doStuff(*res);
else // ... it's not, hence initialize it
   res = std::make_pair(42, 43);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can write a function similar to the following

```
namespace usr
{
    template <class T1, class T2>
    bool empty( const std::pair<T1, T2> &p )
    {
        return p == std::pair<T1, T2>();
    }
}
```

That is a default initialized pair will be considered as ampty.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

namespace usr
{
    template <class T1, class T2>
    bool empty( const std::pair<T1, T2> &p )
    {
        return p == std::pair<T1, T2>();
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::pair<int, int> p1( 1, 2 );

    std::cout << usr::empty( p1 ) << '\n';

    std::pair<int, int> p2;

    std::cout << usr::empty( p2 ) << '\n';
}
```

Its output is

```
0
1
```

Answer (score 3):

This depends on how you define the `std::pair` is *empty*. The default constructor of `std::pair` would value-initialize both elements of the pair, that means for `pair<int, int> res;`, its `first` and `second` would be initialized to `0`. That's the only way you can check for a default-constructed `std::pair`, if they're guaranteed to be non-zero after the assignment.