# How to check if a template pair has value

Tags: c++, templates, trie

i'm coding a trie structure in C++ with a template snippet:

```
pair<char,T>
```

I have a method void empty() in which I want to check, whether the root's **second value** is not set (value is equal to default constructor value or in detail: values would store other pair types.). I know that the default constructor would apply 0 for the data type int, but how can i check this inside the template ?

Another post mentioned this:
return root == new Trie<char,T>() (failed duo to unknown == operator)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Zero is a value, so from that perspective, your question doesn't make sense. Please, start with the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `std::pair` is a value type, so it's always 'set' in the sense that it always has a value.  You want to know if the `T` object is properly initialized?  Well you'll have to ensure that in the code that creates the pair, or else make it a nullable type (such as a pointer).

Comment: It makes sense, because the default constructor would always apply a value and in case of an int it is 0. The question is not about the 0, but the template solution.

Comment: Unrelated: `return root == new Trie<char,T>()` would create an instant memory leak and always return `false`. Where did you find that post?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57109084/check-if-pair-is-empty-or-uninitialized/57109166

Comment: @SebyKiunke I can't find _any_ post doing `return root == new Trie<char,T>()` or any use of `new` at all in that link. I found a suggestion about using `std::optional` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `std::pair`s member cannot be "not set".

You can use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) to model an optional value.

---

> "...value is equal to default constructor..."

Of course you can check if the current value equals the initial one:

```
std::pair<int,int> x;
if (x.first == 0) {
    std::cout << "value of x.first is that of a default constructed std::pair<int,int>";
}
```

Or for the second member of a `std::pair<int,T>`:

```
if (x.second == T{} ) {
    std::cout << "second has same value as a default constructed T";
}
```

Complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
bool check_if_default_second(const std::pair<int,T>& p) {
    return p.second == T{};
}


int main() {
    std::pair<int,int> p;
    std::cout << check_if_default_second(p);
}
```

Comment: I changed the initial question. I can't change the code. Basically the pair.second holds other pairs , which creates a tree. So i want to check if the second value has no pair (or other value) besides the created one from the constructor. In other words. I want to check if the second.vales have ever been touched by code.

Comment: and i have to check the second value, not the first, which is T.

Comment: @SebyKiunke just added a part that specifically adresses your last edit. Wether it is `first` or `second` doesn't change much

Comment: @SebyKiunke fwiw, I know that this does not adress the question you actually want to ask. Thats to some large extend because the question is not quite clear. Sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps open another question where you ask about your actual problem. What makes you think that you need to check if a pairs member has been set? You mention something here, but it is unclear

Comment: But I don't have <int,int>, but <char,T>, so I want to check the "generic"

Comment: @SebyKiunke but this also does not change anything about the answer. You then compare to a default constructed `T`. See edit

Comment: could you please explain: x.second == T{} ?

Comment: @SebyKiunke what dont you understand? It compares the second member of the pair to a default constructed `T`. Thats what you want if I understood the question correctly

Comment: @SebyKiunke note that this is only the best I can provide given what I understood. I still believe that for your actual problem there is a better solution. Specifically when `T` is something that is not trivial to construct you do not want to create a `T` just to check if the member of the pair has been set